# How do I catch a specific async/await error from package?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have tried many ways to try and catch this specific async/await error from a package. I can't seem to catch a specific error. For other errors, it catches it but from this package, node.js does not catch it for some reason. (Sorry if the code is not formatted correctly or has silly mistakes I'm just typing it here.)

I have tried `error` , `error.message`, `error.code`, `error.stack`, `error.toString()`, and `error.message.toString()`.

All of the above do not work to catch my error.

**Using Try Catch**

```
async function main(){
try {
await testExample();
 console.log('Finished!');
} catch (error){
if(error == 'specific error) {
throw new Error('an error has occured');
} else {
console.error(error);
}}}
main();
```

**Using Try Catch Along with .catch attached to function**

```
async function main(){
try {
await testExample().catch(function (error) {
if(error == 'specific error) {
throw new Error('an error has occured');
}
});
 console.log('Finished!');
} catch (error){
if(error == 'specific error) {
throw new Error('an error has occured');
} else {
console.error(error);
}
}}
main();
```

**Using Try Catch Along with .catch, attached to main**

```
async function main(){
try {
await testExample();
 console.log('Finished!');
} catch (error){
if(error == 'specific error) {
throw new Error('an error has occured');
} else {
console.error(error);
}
}}
main().catch(function (error) {
if(error == 'specific error) {
throw new Error('an error has occured');
}
});;
```

**Using await-to-js**

```
const to = promise => promise.then(res => [null, res]).catch(error=> [error|| true, null]);
async function main()
{
    var [error, success] = await to(testExample());
    if(error){
        if(error == 'specific error) {
throw new Error('an error has occured');
} else {
console.error(error);
}
    }
        if(success){
     console.log('Finished!');
main();   
});
```

**Making a promise**

```
async function main(){
await new Promise((resolve, reject => {
   testExample();
}).catch(function (error) {
 if(error == 'specific error) {
throw new Error('an error has occured');
} else {
console.error(error);
}
});

console.log('Finished!');
}
main();
```

**Uncaught Exception**

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(error) {
   if(error == 'specific error) {
throw new Error('an error has occured');
} else {
console.error(error);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of your problem can be found here: https://github.com/fawazahmed0/youtube-uploader/blob/c2a33b0b680db2086be6d4b90a91b0157dca70eb/src/upload.ts#L658-L663

The error you want to catch is thrown in `changeHomePageLangIfNeeded`, but the linked code shows the error is caught and logged, but it isn't passed upstream to your code.

Comment: Yeah  I forgot to mention that I have also tried `error` , `error.message`, `error.code`, `error.stack`, `error.toString()`, and `error.message.toString()`. 

All of the above do not work to catch my error.

Comment: Without more information, it's unlikely someone will be able to help you. What package are you referring to, and what's the error that you can't catch?

Comment: I am using the `youtube-videos-uploader` package. and the error I am encountering is `Error: Avatar/Profile picture button not found : TimeoutError`. It is a thrown error originating from puppeteer, `Error: No node found for selector: button#avatar-btn`. The reason why I didn't mention the package is that it is such an unlikely error to happen.

Comment: What would I need to do it make it pass to my code? I would like to primarily catch this error and then upon encountering this error do something.

Comment: You'd have create your own version of the package that will throw the error instead of just logging it.

Comment: isn't it already being thrown in the package? [here](https://github.com/fawazahmed0/youtube-uploader/blob/c2a33b0b680db2086be6d4b90a91b0157dca70eb/src/upload.ts#L712)

Comment: Yes, and in my answer I'm pointing to the code that is calling that function _and catching the error_. If it gets caught and not rethrown the exception won't reach your code.

Comment: Thank you, I have successfully edited the package to throw the error instead of logging it. Now my code actually catches the error.